# About nodejs AES-128-GCM encryption after the other party can not parse the ciphertext problem

Tags: node.js

According to the project requirements, a set of request data needs to be encrypted using AES-128-GCM, but the encrypted data obtained is always not parsed by the other party.When I use Golang to write the encryption algorithm, the encrypted data can be parsed properly by the other party.

```
function Encrypt(text, key) {
    
    if (!text) {
        return '';
    }
    if (typeof text != 'string') {
        text = JSON.stringify(text);
    }

    const md5 = crypto.createHash('md5');
    
    const result = md5.update(key).digest();

    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(12);


    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-gcm', result, iv);
    cipher.setAutoPadding(0);
    const encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8');

    const finalstr = cipher.final();

    const tag = cipher.getAuthTag();

    const res = Buffer.concat([encrypted, finalstr, tag]);

    return  res.toString('base64');
    
}
```

The above is the encryption code for nodejs, The key passed in '12f41deed45188c8061c840c643baede'

Now I can prove that there is no problem for the other party to parse the cipher text, then the problem can only be a problem in the encryption code of nodejs, please help me to look at the big guys, to solve the problem for me!

The following is the encryption code for golang

```
// golang code

type User struct {
    Ai    string `json:"ai"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    IdNum string `json:"idNum"`
}

func main() {

    u := User{
        Ai:    "200000000000000001",
        Name:  "某二一",
        IdNum: "110000190201010009",
    }

    str, err := json.Marshal(u)

    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println(string(str))
    }


    //NewGCM_encrypt("12f41deed45188c8061c840c643baede", "{\"ai\":\"200000000000000001\",\"name\":\"某二一\",\"idNum\":\"110000190201010009\"}")
}

func NewGCM_encrypt(keyv, s string) string {
    key, _ := hex.DecodeString(keyv)
    //key := hexStringToByte(keyv)
    fmt.Println("key:", key)
    plaintext := []byte(s)

    //fmt.Println("key", string(key))
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    // Never use more than 2^32 random nonces with a given key because of the risk of a repeat.
    nonce := make([]byte, 12)
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, nonce); err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    //nonce, _ = hex.DecodeString("FA9F93725406FD0E4F621B01")
    fmt.Printf("iv:%x\n", nonce)

    //iv := []byte("123456789012")
    aesgcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(block)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    ciphertext := aesgcm.Seal(nil, nonce, plaintext, nil)

    r := append(nonce, ciphertext...)

    //fmt.Println("ciphertext:", ciphertext)
    //fmt.Printf("ciphertext16str:%x\n", ciphertext)
    //r, _ := hex.DecodeString(fmt.Sprintf("%x", ciphertext))
    //fmt.Println("r:", r)
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(r)
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the inputs to your Golang encryption, (text, key, etc) and resulting encrypted data? If you can do this we can understand what's going wrong with the Node.js code. Or, better yet, post the Golang code. Thank you!

Comment: I have added the golang code to the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to include the IV with the encrypted data, in addition to the auth tag, otherwise the other party will not be able to decrypt it.

I've updated to match the Golang code, so the Node.js Encrypt should be decrypted by the same code.

I've also added an example of decrypting the data in Node.js, this may be helpful in diagnosing any issues.

**NB:** Since the IV is random, we won't get the same exact output as the Golang code (or between calls), but it should decrypt correctly.

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

function Encrypt(text, key) {
    
    if (!text) {
        return '';
    }
    if (typeof text != 'string') {
        text = JSON.stringify(text);
    }

    const cipherKey = Buffer.from(key, "hex");
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(12);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-gcm', cipherKey, iv);

    const res = Buffer.concat([iv, cipher.update(text), cipher.final(), cipher.getAuthTag()]);
    return res.toString('base64');    
}

function Decrypt(input, key) {
    
    input = input instanceof Buffer ? input: Buffer.from(input, "base64");
    const tag = input.slice(input.length - 16, input.length);
    const iv = input.slice(0, 12);
    const toDecrypt = input.slice(12, input.length - tag.length);

    const cipherKey = Buffer.from(key, "hex");
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-gcm', cipherKey, iv);
    decipher.setAuthTag(tag);

    const res = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(toDecrypt), decipher.final()]);
    return res.toString('utf8');
}

const key = "12f41deed45188c8061c840c643baede"
const encrypted = Encrypt("Why then 'tis none to you; for there is nothing either good or bad, but thinking makes it so.", key);

console.log("Encrypted data:", encrypted);
console.log("Decrypted:", Decrypt(encrypted, key));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, and thank you for the code, but after using your code, the problem is still not solved, the other party still can't decrypt properly, is there a difference between the encryption library of nodejs and the encryption library of other languages? Have you tried to use this code to encrypt and then decrypt in other languages successfully?

Comment: Thanks for posting the golang code. The Node.js crypto library should produce the same results as other languages, provided all the inputs and options for the encryption process are the same, e.g. padding, mode etc. This can be tricky to achieve! The best way to do this is to compare encryption output with the other languages.

Comment: I've updated the Node.js code, to hopefully work with the other party's code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply again, after using your code, the problem has been perfectly solved, thank you very much, and you learn a lot of things, wish you a happy life!

Comment: Thanks for testing my answer, good luck with the project!!